# Is there a way to access methods inside of an npm package?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently building a website where I need to build a carousel. The carousel needs to have a 'progress bar' as the indicator for the current slide (like here: https://www.samsung.com/uk).

I'm familiar with react-responsive-carousel, but it doesn't have the functionality built in for the progress bar.

I've used state to effectively build a stopwatch to facilitate the progress bar inside my component.

Instead of using the built in autoplay functionality from react-responsive-carousel, I'd like to have a function that is triggered once the interval is finished to move on to the next slide.

The problem I'm having is, I'm not sure how to trigger this action. I've checked the docs, and it looks like I need to trigger onClickNext (see [here](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/src/components/Carousel/index.tsx), line 528), but I can't figure out how to do that.

I'm currently using a functional component, rather than a class based component, if that makes a difference. I just need to understand how I can trigger that action from my component.

Thanks

Comment: _"Instead of using the built in autoplay functionality from react-responsive-carousel, I'd like to have a function that is triggered once the interval is finished to move on to the next slide."_ Can you elaborate why your needs are different than the capabilities that are already provided? It has an `interval` prop which allows you to specify a custom amount of time between transitions.

Comment: There needs to be a progress bar built into the current 'indicator' - you can see an example of this here: https://www.samsung.com/uk/

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this with the standard available props, as you need to have access to where the timer is up to

Comment: The answer is no you can't trigger that externally, and what you're trying to achieve is pretty broad so it's unlikely you'll be able to get help here to accomplish that. You might be better off looking for a more composable carousel implementation to work with that doesn't tie you into very specific behavior

Comment: Is there another way this could potentially be done? I thought a workaround could perhaps be to use javascript to trigger a click of the 'next' arrow, but this feels like a hacky approach.

Any suggestions on alternative carousels packages? I haven't found any that are give me what I need.

Comment: I've dug into this a little further and used useRef to get access to the 'next' button as a variable. The 'current.Onclick' function is blank, but there is a property called [[FunctionLocation]] within onClick that references the onClickNext function in the upper scope. Is there no way to execute it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe triggering the function inside of that class component using a ref is the way.

It seems to be the solution you're looking for.

```
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (myRef) myRef.current.onClickNext();
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Carousel ref={myRef}>
      <div>
        <p>Slide 1</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Slide 2</p>
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks for answering. I'm at this stage with it now actually, but this approach seems a little hacky. I was hoping to be able to trigger the function directly but it seems like it might not be possible